# Laravel getting data from another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables :

**Accessories**
id,code,details

**PriceRevision**
id,accessories_id,revised_price

and I am trying to get following json:

```
[
{ "id": 1, "code": "G4007", "detail": "Flyscreen round Gasket -7", "revised_price::25 }
,
{ "id": 2, "code": "CZBR-100S", "detail": "Single Bearing Roller " "revised_price::35 }
]
```

how do i combine the two table to get the above result?I am assuming I'll have to join those two tables?

I have done something like this but only get data of accessories table:

```
$data3=InventoryAccessories::select('id','code','sl_detail')
        ->get();

        foreach ($data3 as $d) {
            $data4=ProductPriceRevision::select('revised_price')->get();
            # code...
        }

        return $data3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like `$model->with('relation');`

Answer (score 0):

If you using Laravel's `eloquent` ORM then you can do it by simply setting a relationship(one to many, many to many etc) between your two table. Then you can do access the one table form another just like:

```
$accessories = InventoryAccessories::all();
$accessories->priceRevision->revised_price;
```

Where `$accessories` is a variable that just contains all accessories from the db using `eloquent`. 
Then you can just format the data to generate your desired json.
Here you can find the the way to set up relation between two tables: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Otherwise you can just make a query by joining two table using Query Builder to get those data from db. Here you can find how to join two tables using query builder: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins